# Blackberry app approved by vendor – again to resubmit after adding new devices?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

Our Android runtime blackberry app has been approved by vendor portal recently and its on blackberry world store. While approving we selected only one device from the list of devices shown in portal. Now I want to add more devices, I have selected required devices and saved it. My doubt is

1. Do I need to resubmit the app again in order to list app in blackberry world for the newly added devices? Right now while searching app on BB store, its shown only on the device I selected for the first time. Now I want it on newly added device also.
2. Just saving the devices alone is enough?
3. If I need to resubmit how many days it would take the for approval?

I researched on internet, I didn’t get required information

Comment: No need to upload again. Add new devices and save it. It will take some time for the new update.

Comment: @Signare, Thanks for your comment. I followed this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243901/submit-multiple-bundle-to-blackberry-app-world) thread and gave new release by adding required devices. We added new devices in previous release and saved it and we gave new release also. Would it give any issues?

Comment: no, the new release will update the old one.

Comment: But we didn't enable the devices which we were already enabled in old build, would that stop working after replacing newer version. Also How long it will take for approval?, as we didn't change anything in bundle, we submitted on 6th Feb, still its under review.

Comment: Maybe. I am not sure about that. Maximum 15 days. As per my experience, within 5-7 days your app will be released/rejected.